# Get Date Range for Cassandra - Select timeuuid with IN returning 0 rows

Tags: cassandra, cql

I'm trying to get data from a date range on Cassandra, the table is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test6 (
  time timeuuid,
  id text,
  checked boolean,
  email text,
  name text,
  PRIMARY KEY ((time), id)
)
```

But when I select a data range I get nothing:

```
SELECT * FROM teste WHERE time IN ( minTimeuuid('2013-01-01 00:05+0000'), now() );

(0 rows)
```

How can I get a date range from a Cassandra Query?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `IN` condition is used to specify multiple keys for a [SELECT](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/select_r.html) query.  To run a date range query for your table, (you're close) but you'll want to use greater-than and less-than.

Of course, you can't run a greater-than/less-than query on a partition key, so you'll need to flip your keys for this to work.  This also means that you'll need to specify your `id` in the WHERE clause, as well:

```
CREATE TABLE teste6 (
  time timeuuid,
  id text,
  checked boolean,
  email text,
  name text,
  PRIMARY KEY ((id), time)
)

INSERT INTO teste6 (time,id,checked,email,name)
VALUES (now(),'B26354',true,'rdeckard@lapd.gov','Rick Deckard');

SELECT * FROM teste6 
WHERE id='B26354'
AND time >= minTimeuuid('2013-01-01 00:05+0000')
AND time <= now();

 id     | time                                 | checked | email             | name
--------+--------------------------------------+---------+-------------------+--------------
 B26354 | bf0711f0-b87a-11e4-9dbe-21b264d4c94d |    True | rdeckard@lapd.gov | Rick Deckard

(1 rows)
```

Now while this will technically work, partitioning your data by `id` might not work for your application.  So you may need to put some more thought behind your data model and come up with a better partition key.

**Edit:**

Remember with Cassandra, the idea is to get a handle on what kind of queries you need to be able to fulfill.  Then build your data model around that.  Your original table structure might work well for a relational database, but in Cassandra that type of model actually makes it difficult to query your data in the way that you're asking.

Take a look at the modifications that I have made to your table (basically, I just reversed your partition and clustering keys).  If you still need help, Patrick McFadin (DataStax's Chief Evangelist) wrote a really good article called [Getting Started with Time Series Data Modeling](http://planetcassandra.org/blog/getting-started-with-time-series-data-modeling/).  He has three examples that are similar to yours.  In fact his first one is very similar to what I have suggested for you here.

Comment: There is no way to search just with a range of date, even when it is a timeuuid?

Comment: @CaeVecchi Not when that timeuuid is your partition key.  Partition keys aren't stored in order by value, so querying a range of them doesn't work.

Comment: I mean, to get the range of the date.

Comment: @CaeVecchi Edit made.